# List of available fonts with samples

Tags: software-rec, fonts

I want to list all installed fonts on my system and view them to choose one for some purpose. How is that possible? Is there a program, which can provide sort of gallery of installed fonts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There many of these utilities available - search your repository with 'font view' query.

Examples:

- fontviewer: http://siyb.mount.at/scripts/
- fontpage: http://www.absolutelinux.org/FONTpage.shtml
- fontypython: https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/fontypython/

Answer (score 4):

**fontmatrix** (a feature-full personal font manager) has a concept of 'tagging'. This makes it really nice to group  fonts and even sub-group them logically for use in a book for instance.   It also has extensive gui support for showing all glyphs in a font, previews of sample text, variable sizing and also

and (maybe) **fontforge**  .. but it offers a bit too much for me ;) ..

Answer (score -1):

Or python based script inside Scribus.